# Azure Stream Analytics grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, azure-stream-analytics

Does a grammar exist for Azure Stream Analytics query language?
[Like this one](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/554/Syllabus/5-query-opt/SQL-grammar.html)

Comment: Would you mind letting me know why you need the entire grammar? I'm very curious about what it is you're building :)

Comment: I have to parse and validate a query before sending it for execution. I have not found any ready solution for that (I'm using the [java lib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager-streamanalytics-readme?view=azure-java-preview) which is not able to do that and I also can't find something like that at the [REST documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/) page). So I decided to generate the parser using [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) and I need grammar for that.

Comment: Have you though about unit testing your queries to validate them? We have a module that does just that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/cicd-tools?tabs=visual-studio-code#automated-test

Comment: That same module has a build method that compiles the job and check for syntax errors in the query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/cicd-tools?tabs=visual-studio-code#build-the-project

Comment: No, it does not fit me, because I have to create Stream Analytics jobs on the fly and I need to have an abbility to take a part of query such as "from aliases" and "into aliases".
But thank you for your attempt to help.

Comment: Let me check internally if there's anything more we can do. It may take some time though.

Comment: Sorry but at the moment we don't have a plan to publish a complete grammar. Hopefully you'll find a way around.

Answer (score 0):

Each individual article [in the language doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/stream-analytics-query-language-reference) has its grammar included.

For example [SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/select-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json):

```
SELECT <select_list>   
<select_list> ::=   
    {   
      *   
      | { input_name |  input_alias }.*   
      | {  
          [ { input_name | input_alias }. ]  
               { column_name }  
     | expression [ [ AS ] column_alias ]  
         }  
      | column_alias = expression   
    } [ ,...n ]
```

Or [FROM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/from-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json):

```
FROM <input_source> [<PARTITION BY clause>] [<TIMESTAMP BY clause>]
  
<PARTITION BY clause> ::== PARTITION BY <key_spec>

<TIMESTAMP BY clause> ::== TIMESTAMP BY scalar_expression [OVER <key_spec>]

<input_source> ::=   
    {   
      *   
      | { input_name |  input_alias }.*   
      | {  
          [ { input_name | input_alias }. ]  
               { column_name }  
     | expression [ [ AS ] column_alias ]  
         }  
      | column_alias = expression   
    }

<key_spec> ::== { column_name | expression } [,... n]
```

I don't think we have that published as a single document though.